# using several query in cursor in android

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

i want to go to some information in sqllite database in android.but i dont know what.
my code is:

```js
 public Cursor getData() {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT text,_id from tbl_laws where parent_id = 0",null);
        // Note: Master is the one table in External db. Here we trying to access the records of table from external db.


        Cursor c1 = db.rawQuery("SELECT text,_id from tbl_nokte where parent_id = 0",null);
        // Note: Master is the one table in External db. Here we trying to access the records of table from external db.
        return c;
        return c1;
    }
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to adjust your SQL-Select-Query.

You already use a rawQuery to get the information, but for two different Cusors. This will not work.

The Solution to get your needed information with a single cursor could be:

```
public Cursor getData() {
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    String query = "SELECT laws._id, laws.text," +
                          " nokt._id,nokt.text" +
                   " FROM tbl_laws AS laws, tbl_nokte AS nokt" +
                   " WHERE laws.parent_id = 0 AND nokt.parent_id = 0";


    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    return c;
}
```

The usage would be:

```
public List<YourObject> getDataForYourObjects(Cursor c){
    List<YourObject> yourObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    if(c != null){
       while(c.moveToNext(){
          //law results
          long lawsID = c.getLong(0);
          String lawsText = c.getString(1);

          //nokt results
          long noktID = c.getLong(2);
          String noktText = c.getString(3);

          YourObject yo = new YourObject();
          yo.addLaw(lawID, lawText);
          yo.addNokt(noktID, noktText);
          yourObjects.add(yo);
       }
       c.close();
    }
    return yourObjects;
}
```

(The example code above is not tested!)

Hope it helps.

Additonal, you can look into a SQLite tutorial like:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/ to get mor familiar with sqlite.

Also have a look in to a android SQLite Tutorial like:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm
to get more information what is possible with Anroids-SQLite and the cursor object.

Comment: thank you for help. but I want to use several listview by informtion from database. i want i want to get several query and use in several class can you help me?